# Issues compiling nodejs code with ts-node (Cannot use import statement outside a module)

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

When attempting to compile typescript code with NodeJS using the following command:

```
npx ts-node src/server.ts
```

I receive the following error:

```
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

I followed the instructions suggested by the error:

> Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the
> package.json or use the .mjs extension.

But upon following these, I still had no luck and another error was thrown instead.

Here is the content of my server.ts file.

```
import App from './app';
const app = new App();
app.listen(3080);
```

tsconfig.json contents:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2017",
    "lib": ["es2017"],
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "pretty": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "allowJs": true,
    "noEmit": false,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["*"],
    }
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.json", ".env"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

I'm not really sure what is causing this but would greatly appreciate some wisdom on the issue.

Ideally i'd like to load the app via the server.ts file, while maintaining TypeScript contents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need `"moduleResolution": "node"` in the `compilerOptions` for ts to recognize these types of imports.